# Could someone give an easily understandable explanation of "derivation rules"?

Tags: terminology, derivation

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form), A BNF specification is a set of **derivation rules**.

The post [Term for a non-word consistent with derivation rules](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/6321/28013) **on this site** also uses this term.

Google returns [a lot of results](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20%22derivation%20rules%22), [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/derivation-rule) is one of them, just using without explaining what it is.

Could someone give an easily understandable explanation of this term?

Comment: They're the rules which govern how languages derive words from other words. For example,  in English you add *-able* to turn a verb into an adjective.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about linguistics. I understand it as a question about formal languages as in Theoretical Computer Science described by BNF.

Comment: Derivation rules describe the (possibly recursive) hierarchical structure of well-formed sentences (in natural languages) or, more generally, sequences of tokens (in formal languages such as programming languages). Simply speaking, they describe word order and (to some extent) head-argument relations.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica Did you notice the post **on this site** I linked?

Comment: @JJJohn There are multiple meanings for the term "derivation rules". The derivation rules used in BNF are different from the derivation rules that turn "take" into "taking"; the latter is definitely linguistics, but the former tends to fall under computer science instead (even if linguists do make use of them).

Comment: That said, I think it's fine to have the question on this site, even if it would also be appropriate on CS.SE or others. The types of "derivation rules" being asked about are the foundation of constituency grammars, and I'm assuming that's the context in which the asker found the term (hence asking it here instead of on Math or CS).